# Powershell, Excel find string in column

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a Workbook that's already open. I go into a specific worksheet, search for a string in a column, move 3 cells over to the right and get the value of that cell in a variable. But Excel just isn't finding that string.

```
$File = "D:\Bank\UBS\KD_eMail.xlsx\Debitorenliste BESR.xlsm"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$RGFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("RG-Nummer eingeben (33xxxx)", "RG-Nummer")

$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)

$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("KD_RG_eMail_path")
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
$SearchSrting = $RGFileName
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)
#$Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 3)
$RGPath = $Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 3)
```

Now, if I get the data from a seperate workbook it works perfectly. What am I missing?

```
$File = "D:\Bank\QR_ES\4_Adr_Excel\KD_eMail.xlsx"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$RGFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("RG-Nummer eingeben (33xxxx)", "RG-Nummer")

$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)

$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("KD_RG")
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($RGFileName)
$Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 2)
$RGPath = $Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 2)
$RGPath = $RGPath.Value()
```

Comment: You really need to specify additional parameters of `Find` as I commented on your last question.

Comment: But like what? I need it to find that `$SearchString` and it just doesn't. I made different tests and it turned out that the error is in the line `$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)`. I just can't understand why or where

Comment: Does that string actually exist? What does `$RGFileName` return when piped to `Get-Member`?

Comment: Don't know if it's just a typo when posting, but `$SearchSrting`

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question but stated explicitly here: from the [`Find` docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find?view=excel-pia#remarks): The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method..... To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method. You're only using the `What` (first) parameter. At a minimum you need to specify `LookIn` and `LookAt` too. The latest settings for `LookIn` and `LookAt` might not be what you want, so set them explicitly.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala $RGFileName | Get-Member -> TypeName: System.String

Comment: Changed the code, please take a look everybody

Comment: @BigBen, that's just saying if you set them at some point they will stick and be used subsequent times.  He is not setting them so that doesn't apply.

Comment: @Daniel it does apply, because if not specified the *current* values are used, which may not be what you want. This is a very common issue in VBA threads using `Find` and the same applies here. It is a very unfortunate "feature" of `Find`.

Comment: Ok @BigBen, I hear you.  The language does mention taking settings from the find dialog, whatever they may be, if not provided explicitly.  Could explain why ASD is saying that it works when pulling from a separate workbook.

Comment: I solved it guys. Could it be the problem was because the value i was looking for was the result of a formula and not just a plain value?